# Salesforce Social Customer Service: "reply" link in Social Post is not working

Tags: servicecloud, facebook, feedcomment, social-content, socialpost

I have enabled Social Customer Service and installed starter pack.

I created one facebook page and added that page in SOCIAL ACCOUNTS under social customer service settings.

When a user posts something on facebook page, a case record for that user gets created in Salesforce and I can see that post in "Social Post" action in case feed layout.

There are 3 links per social post: Comment, Like and View Source.
Like and View Source links are working. 
But "comment" link is not working. When I click on Comment link, nothing happens.

Could you please suggest what is missing?

*Predefined text values for Name and Headline fields:*
[image]

Comment: Have you set up the predefined values for the quick action fields - https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=social_customer_service_custom_pub.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Yes! I have created predefined text values for Name and Headline fields, screenshot added in the question.

Comment: I am not able to find like button in my social post it only shows view source and comment. How did you get the like button? @SantanuHalder

Comment: @SagarHinsu I was facing same issue and my issue was resolved by adding permission set.. you can have a look https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=social_customer_service_setup_permissions.htm&type=5